# How can I detect in an app that Proguard successfully removed all log calls?

Tags: android, logging, proguard

Thanks to Proguard's optimization features I am now able to do as much debug-logging as I which in my code - for production I simply let it strip all this unnecessary code.

That is fine and works (with the latest Proguard version).

But: before I went this way, I had my `final static boolean DEBUG` constant that "guarded" all my `Log.d`/`Log.v` calls. To ensure I did not forget to disable that for signed production apk's, I just had an *easily* visible add on in my UI main activity that in some corner put an ugly text "DEBUG IS ON".

So, when producing my final apk, all I had to do is install it once - in case I forgot to switch debug mode off, I was reminded by that.

Now, with Proguard doing the work of removing debug-log-calls: how could I DETECT that in my app and control a UI element that states "DEBUG IS ON"?
Any idea?

My first attempt was to try this:

```
boolean loggingEnabled = false;
Log.d(TAG, (loggingEnabled = true) ? "Logging test" : "");
```

And I hoped that Proguard would also remove the assignment `loggingEnabled=true`- but I underestimated Proguard. It removes the call to `Log.d`, but still does the assignment... :)

Comment: What do you mean by "detect"? Do you want to know, if your app is running in `DEBUG` mode, or do you want to be sure, `Log.d()` calls are removed?

Comment: I want a variable IN my app that is either true or false, depending on whether Proguard has removed all log.d /.v calls or not.

Comment: Why not just using `BuildConfig.DEBUG`?

Comment: Does `BuildConfig.DEBUG` correlate to Proguard optimizing? Is that constant set by Proguard?

Comment: It's a constant set by gradle, the new Android build system. Normally, you use proguard only for release builds. In most scenarios, this is `RELEASE==!DEBUG`. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a few things:

- Check the mapping.txt in proguard's output folder: `grep -E '(android/util/|de/ub0r/android/logg0r/)Log.[dv]' */build/proguard/release/dump.txt`
- Run the app and check if any d/v log is printed.
- Decompilte the app and look at the source code for calls to `Log.d()` and `Log.v()`.

I build a simple wrapper library to make it a little bit more handy:

https://github.com/felixb/ub0rlogg0r

--- EDIT ---

To Check if your logs got stripped, do the following:

1. Fork ub0rlogg0r.
2. Add a `public static boolean sHasDebugCalls = false;` to `Log`.
3. Add `sHasDebugCalls = true` to all the `Log.d()` and `Log.v()` methods.
4. Place a `Log.d(TAG, "has debug logs")` somewhere in the very beginning of your app.
5. When creating your UI, test for `Log.sHasDebugCalls` to decide visibility of the DEBUG reminder.

Comment: Yeah, I could. But I want that the APK itself can detect whether log calls were removed or not. I want a visual reminder IN the app that tells me "hey, this apk is NOT to be published!". What exactly is the benefit of your wrapper? I thought that when Proguard removes for example a log.d call, all Strings used there are also removed?

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question. sorry for that. With the wrapper, you can replace `Log.d(TAG, "key="+value)` with `Log.d(TAG, "key=", value)`. It prints the same, but the first get's replaced by the compiler by a Series of `StringBuilder` calls. Proguard will remove the call to `Log.d`, but the `StringBuilder` will remain. My wrapper moves the `StringBuilder` **into** the `Log.d` which get's stripped by proguard completely.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought that because of several optimizing loops, all the remainders - including the StringBuilders - are removed completely! That's what I expect Proguard to do! Gee... I think I go back to doing it myself... :-)

Comment: I modified the answer to answer your question. ;) BTW: inside my wrapper code is a link to a good SO thread you should read. It explains, why my wrapper is necessary.  In the end, it's about side effects proguard can not now anything about.

Comment: Thanks - that sounds like a solution! :) I try that! BTW: WebSMS is cool, thanks for that as well! ;-)